# How do I update an array within a document using existing values (for concatenation)?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to update the following document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "44163fdce26d651e230e5f7"
  },
  "views": {
    "cardView": {
      "listOptions": {
        "addViewKey": null,
        "editViewKey": null,
        "listSortFieldKeys": [
          "Name",
          "Element"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change the "listSortFieldKeys" array, reusing the old value.
For example, update every value in the array to "old value" + "_test".
This would then result in:

```
"listSortFieldKeys": [
          "Name_test",
          "Element_test"
        ]
```

I am using the `updateMany` function as follows:

```
db.getCollection("entityInfos")
   .updateMany({ 'views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys': 
       { $exists: true, $ne: null }}, [{ $set: { 
         "views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys.$[]": { $concat: 
         ['views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys.$[]', '_test'] } }}])
```

*I get the error: Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using update with pipeline (`[]`) with syntax of regular update (`.$[]` to update all items). In this case, one option is indeed to use update with pipeline, but with a proper pipeline syntax, such as `$map`:

```
db.collection.update({
  "views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys": {
    $exists: true,
    $ne: null
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys": {
        $map: {
          input: "$views.cardView.listOptions.listSortFieldKeys",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$this",
              "_test"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1tahJ5IZktH)